# How to sum() values derived from count()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a chart with the total number of incidents based on tier. the values in tot_incidents is derived from count() function. I want to add a third column, percentage, with the values from tot_incidents divided by the total of the tot_incidents column.

```
tier    tot_incidents
1       77
2       27
3       47
4       2
```

When I try `incidents/(sum(incidents)) as SNOW_prct`
I get the lovely message 'ERROR: aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function
SNOW alerts by app tier'

I've looked at cases and subqueries but I can't get the code working for my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select . . . ,
       incidents / sum(incidents) over () as SNOW_ratio
from t;
```

Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8.0.